# Try to calculate 2 values from callback (Binance Api using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, api, callback, binance

I have 2 different code to get data:
first is to get by balance account
the second is to get the current value of the coin
I need to calculate the number of coins that I can buy with the balance
(Balance*coin value = quantity)

I have tried many options to get the value outside of the function without luck.

first code: (get balance)

```
    binance.balance((error, balances) => {
    if ( error ) return console.error(error);
    console.info("BTT balance: ", balances.BTT.available);
    });
```

Second code (get coin value)

```
    binance.prices('BTTUSDT',(error, ticker)=>{
    console.info("Hello:: ", ticker.BTTUSDT);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Dive in callback hell:

```js
binance.balance((error, balances) => {
  if ( error ) return console.error(error);
  console.info("BTT balance: ", balances.BTT.available);

  binance.prices('BTTUSDT',(error, ticker)=>{
    if ( error ) return console.error(error);

    // Balance*coin
  });
});
```

Or use Promises:

```js
const getBalance = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  binance.balance((error, balances) => {
  if(error) {
    reject(error);
    return;
  }

  resolve(balances.BTT.available);
});

const getCoins = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  binance.prices('BTTUSDT', (error, ticker) => {
  if(error) {
    reject(error);
    return;
  }

  resolve(ticker.BTTUSDT);
});


(async () => {
  const balance = await getBalance();
  const coins = await getCoins();

  console.info(balance * coins);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer, It's helped me a lot.

Comment: @ygalbrami It's a good practice to upvote useful answers. Also if there is an answer that solved your problem, please, mark it as an accepted answer.